# Slow HTTPURLConnection in Android

Tags: java, android, http, get

I use the following code

```
private String resultGET(String addr)
{
 try
 {
  String result = "";
  HttpURLConnection conn = null;
  addr = (isFull)?addr:Statics.fullURL(addr);
  try
  {
   URL url = new URL(addr);
   conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
   conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
   conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", Statics.USER_AGENT);
   InputStream ips = conn.getInputStream();

   int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
   if (200 != responseCode)
   {
    Feedback.setError("GET error: " + responseCode + " on " + addr); 
    return "";
   }

   BufferedReader bufr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips));
   String line;
   while ((line = bufr.readLine()) != null) result += line; 
   bufr.close();
  } finally{if (null != conn) conn.disconnect();} 
  return result;
 } catch(Exception e)
 {
  Feedback.setError("get fault " + Utils.stackTrace(e));    
  return "";    
 } 
}
```

`Feedback` is simply a Java class I use internally to handle all messages that I send back to the Android app front end (this is a hybrid app and the code above is part of a plugin I have written for the app).

I find that when any significant amount of data are returned the `resultGET`call gets excruciatingly slow.  For instance, a 43Kb Javascript file - which I later use to run JS code via Duktape takes the best part of 1 minute to download and save.

I am still quite a newbie when it comes to Java so I imagine that I am doing something wrong here which is causing the issue.  I'd be most obliged to anyone who might be able to put me on the right track.

---

A while later...

I have now tested the issue on an Android 6 device instead of my default Android 4.4.2 device.  On the Android 6 the download + file save speed comes in at a decent 5 seconds.  On Android 4.4.2 it is over 40s.  Are there any known issues with HTTPURLConnection on earlier versions of Android? I

Comment: Try Http free and efficient libraries like Retrofit http://www.journaldev.com/13639/retrofit-android-example-tutorial  or Volley https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-volley--cms-23800  These are much efficient and performers than your sample

Comment: I do not believe that those will be faster. No reason.

Comment: `download + file save` You are not saving to a file. If you did you did not even need a StringBuilder but could write line by line directly to a -buffered- FileOutputStream.

Comment: True.  `resultGET` is a generic routine that I call from several places.  At times I consume the string result internally, at other times I save to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  String result = "";
```

The += operator on a String is slow. If you have a lot of lines use a StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); and use its append() method to sb.append(line + " \n");

At the end you can use result = sb.toString();

Comment: Switching to StringBuilder improves the Android 4.4.2 performance three fold - from 45s to 15s.  On Android 6 it goes down from 5s to 2.5s.  Nice but still wanting - on my desktop browser (same network) this download happens within a fraction of a second

Comment: A tip for anyone else running into this thread - for good measure I tried replacing my code with calls to the [OkHTTP](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) library.  With the `StringBuilder` replacement in, as suggested by @greenapps, there was no measurable difference in performance.  If anything, it took 2 seconds longer (17s as opposed to 15 on my Android 4.4.2 device and 2.8 instead of 2.5s on my Android 6 device).